# CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints: what attributes can be set?

Tags: ios, core-foundation, core-text

The documentation for `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` describes the `frameAttributes` parameter as so:

> Additional attributes that control the frame filling process, or NULL if there are no such attributes.

I've only ever set this parameter to NULL and can't seem to find any documentation on what I can set these attributes to. The `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` also takes a frameAttributes parameter, but there's no documentation there, either.

Does anyone know where the documentation for these parameters is?

Comment: You should be aware that, as of Snow Leopard (I haven't re-tested on Lion) and iOS 4.3, that function returns nonsense measurements, as do the UIKit methods that are presumably based on it. I don't know of a method that correctly measures the string on 4.3.

Comment: That's the reason I'm looking into those attributes, on the off chance they can at least give me some insight into how those measurements will be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

That parameter is named `frameAttributes`, which implies that they're the same attributes that would be valid when [creating a frame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterCreateFrame) and that you might retrieve by [asking the frame for them](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFrameGetFrameAttributes).

The documentation doesn't directly say what attributes a frame can have. However, it does have, in the CTFrame reference, constants named [`kCTFrameProgressionAttributeName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCTFrameProgressionAttributeName), [`kCTFramePathFillRuleAttributeName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005113-CH4-SW10), and [`kCTFramePathWidthAttributeName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFrameRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005113-CH4-SW12), along with constants for the values for the two that require constant values.

So, educated guess: Those attributes.